# Bluetooth, start communication with already connected device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to get the Bluetooth device(s) that are already connected (not only paired) to my Android phone. Then after, I want to start communication with a connected device. That's all.

I'm surprised why I couldn't find this question answered already. I could only find how to get Paired devices, but nobody is talking about, how get Connected Device(s). :/